# Time it takes to reach maximum current?

Tags: current, resistance, electromagnetism, inductance, time

While studying inductors, I learned that it will take some time for current to reach it's rated value \$ I\$, and considered in "steady state".

Is the same applied for singular wires(not forming a loop/multiple turn loop)? In general, if a wire with low resistance and possibly low inductance had DC flowing, will it time a short duration of time to reach maximum current? Using this equation: \$ t = \frac {L}{R} \$.

From the equation above, that's the time it takes for current to reach \$ \frac {2}{3} \$ it's value?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "not form a loop"?  A loop and a coil are separate concepts.  Draw a picture if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the same applied for singular wires(not forming a loop/multiple
>   turn loop)?

The example you ask for consideration is an imposibility. If a wire passes current then it **MUST** have a return path to the signal source and this forms a loop. Even a monopole antenna passes current and has a return path even though physically it looks like a wire with a connector at one end.

Having made my rant, you can theoretically predict that a wire does have self-inductance and that inductance is maximum when the "return path" is a gazillion miles away: -

[image]http://latex.eeweb.com/eq.latex?L%3D2l%5Cleft%20(%20%5Cln%20%5Cleft%20(%20%5Cleft%20(%20%5Cfrac%7B2l%7D%7Bd%7D%20%5Cright%20)%5Cleft%20(%201%2B%5Csqrt%7B1+%5Cleft%20(%20%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7B2l%7D%20%5Cright%20)%5E%7B2%7D%7D%20%5Cright%20)%20%5Cright%20)-%5Csqrt%7B1+%5Cleft%20(%20%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7B2l%7D%20%5Cright%20)%5E%7B2%7D%7D+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmu%20%7D%7B4%7D+%5Cleft%20(%20%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7B2l%7D%20%5Cright%20)%20%5Cright%20)

Where "l" is the wire length and "d" is the diameter.

> From the equation above, that's the time it takes for current to reach
>   2/3 it's value?

No, it's not two thirds it's 0.63212055882 or \$1-e^{-1}\$

Comment: I wonder if the OP should have used the term "form a coil" instead of "form a loop".  A coil will experience a slower rise time (due to back-EMF in adjacent turns of wire) than a straight section of wire all other factors being equal.  Straight sections of wire (such as a trace on a PCB) will have a rise time due to the fact that real physical circuits are subject to unwanted phenomena such as capacitance and other minor annoyances.

Comment: The OP said NOT forming a loop

Comment: Andy, yes I think it might be a nomenclature issue.  I think the OP is talking about inductors and straight wires (eg going from one terminal of a battery to the other without any formed coils in it).  The OP may be using "loop" and "coil" synonymously when that might not be the intention.

Comment: I fail to see the relevance of your observation on my answer. Sorry!

Comment: I didn't mean any offense.

Comment: @Wossname I _think_ Andy's point is essentially that it's not possible to talk about the inductance of a wire, with current mysteriously entering at some point in space and mysteriously exiting at some other point in space (with tangential magnetic flux density constrained to zero on the exterior boundaries.) If you attempt to perform the integral, you find that the inductance computed depends on the volume of space around the wire you include and it doesn't converge. A magnetic field model has to include a return path to get meaningful self-inductance results. But I may be wrong.

Comment: @jonk And Wossname's point is that OP likely never intended to ask us to do that (analyze a circuit that isn't a circuit)

Comment: @ThePhoton I was just trying to help Wossname understand where Andy was headed. I also semi-get where the OP was probably headed, too. But not enough so, that I feel I could attempt an answer to it.